# how to set QTextEdit color when the text is found or selected?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to set background color when text of QTextEdit is selected or found. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need qss properties `selection-color` and `selection-background-color` for your textedit.

```
selection-color: rgb(170, 255, 0);
selection-background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
```